# Converting from xarray dataarray to numpy ndarray is painfully slow

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, python-xarray, numpy-slicing

I have an xarray dataarray 'T' of size (1456,50,534). The following command takes a couple of minutes to execute:

```
T.isel(x=1,y=10,z=200).values
```

The exact indices of the coordinate are not important as it is slow regardless. I came across another older thread with a similar problem and the suggestion was that using smaller chunks while loading the data might help. But the array in my case is created with the 'isel' option from another larger array (i.e. not loaded from a file). In any case, I tried reducing the chunk size while slicing the larger variable. It makes no difference as converting the newly created array to a numpy array using 'values' is still painfully slow. Is there a way around this? Thanks.

Comment: You could try to write an equivalent in Pandas to see if it is also slow there.

Comment: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/pandas.html

Comment: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/faq.html

Comment: There's really not enough information to help here; how is the array backed? Can you show a reproducible example?

Comment: Hi Maximilian, Is there any way I can attach an html file? I made one (from a notebook) showing how that array was created.